# Нужна ли запятая?

Tags: пунктуация

Администрация города будет и в дальнейшем прикладывать максимум усилий, чтобы освободить город от уродующих внешний облик Ялты самовольно установленных нестационарных объектов

Answer (score 2):

Дополнительных запятых здесь не нужно: здесь два разнородных определительных оборота (один выражает происхождение, другой - приписываемое свойство; они не требют разделения запятой) *предшествуют* определяемому существительному (не требуется отделение от него запятой).

Answer (score 0):

**Предлагаются варианты:**

1) Администрация города будет и в дальнейшем прикладывать максимум усилий, чтобы освободить город от **самовольно установленных, уродующих внешний облик Ялты**  нестационарных объектов. Также можно использовать вместо запятой союз И.

Здесь три определения: два причастных оборота + относительное прилагтельное. Два распространенных оборота в препозиции сложно читаются, поэтому их можно считать однородными (сближенными по значению) и разделить запятой.

2) Администрация города будет и в дальнейшем прикладывать максимум усилий, чтобы освободить город от **самовольно установленных** нестационарных объектов, **уродующих внешний облик Ялты**.